# JavaFX solar system simulation - Sun moving despite being set as immovable

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a simulation of a solar system using JavaFX. I have a class CelestialBody representing each celestial body, and an additional boolean field isImmovable which is supposed to control whether a celestial body is affected by gravitational forces or not. The idea was to make the Sun immovable, while planets orbit around it.

My problem is that despite setting the Sun as immovable (isImmovable = true), it still moves around in the simulation as if it is being influenced by the gravity of other celestial bodies.

Here is the constructor for the CelestialBody class:

```
public CelestialBody(String name, double mass, double radius, Vector3D position, Vector3D velocity, String textureFilename, double orbitalSpeed, boolean isImmovable) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mass = mass;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.textureFilename = textureFilename;
    this.rotationAngle = 0.0;
    this.orbitalSpeed = orbitalSpeed;
    this.isImmovable = isImmovable;
}
```

And here is how I initialize the Sun:

```
CelestialBody sunBody = new CelestialBody("Sun", 1.989 * Math.pow(10, 30), 15.0 * earthRadius, new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), zeroVelocity, "sun.jpg", 0.0, true);
```

In the part of the code that calculates the new position for each celestial body, I have the following:

```
if (!body.isImmovable()) {
    // Here I calculate and update the new position for the celestial body
}
```

This should skip the position update for the Sun, however, it still moves. Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case and how I could fix this? Any help would be much appreciated.
[image]

MainApp:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        SolarSystem solarSystem = initSolarSystem();
        SolarSystemSimulation simulation = new SolarSystemSimulation(solarSystem);

        // Stworzenie AnchorPane i dodanie do niego symulacji
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().add(simulation);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(simulation, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(simulation, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(simulation, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(simulation, 0.0);

        // Wczytanie obrazu tła i ustawienie go jako tła dla sceny
        Image spaceBackground = new Image(getClass().getResource("/space_background.jpg").toExternalForm());
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(new ImagePattern(spaceBackground), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 900);

        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.setNearClip(0.0001);
        camera.setFarClip(900.0);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-30);
        camera.setRotate(0); // Dodaj obroty
        camera.setTranslateY(0); // Dodaj przesunięcie
        camera.setTranslateX(0); // Dodaj przesunięcie
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        // Przesuwanie symulacji, aby środek symulacji pokrywał się ze środkiem ekranu
        simulation.setTranslateX(scene.getWidth() / 2);
        simulation.setTranslateY(scene.getHeight() / 2);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        simulation.start();

        // Ustawienie większego promienia dla słońca
        DisplayedCelestialBody sun = solarSystem.getBodies().get(0);
        sun.getCelestialBody().setRadius(1000);

        // Dodanie obsługi zdarzenia scroll na scenie
        scene.setOnScroll(event -> {
            double delta = event.getDeltaY();
            camera.setTranslateZ(camera.getTranslateZ() + delta);
        });
    }

    private SolarSystem initSolarSystem() {
        SolarSystem solarSystem = new SolarSystem();

        double earthRadius = 1.0;
        double oneAU = 50.0;
        double earthOrbitalPeriod = 365.25;  // Okres orbitalny Ziemi

        Vector3D zeroVelocity = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);

        CelestialBody sunBody = new CelestialBody("Sun", 1.989 * Math.pow(10, 30), 15.0 * earthRadius, new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), zeroVelocity, "sun.jpg", 0.0,true);;
        Sphere sunSphere = new Sphere(sunBody.getRadius());
        DisplayedCelestialBody sun = new DisplayedCelestialBody(sunBody, sunSphere);
        solarSystem.addBody(sun);

        // Dodajemy resztę ciał niebieskich
        String[] planetNames = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
        double[] planetSizes = {0.383, 0.949, 1.0, 0.532, 11.21, 9.45, 4.01, 3.88};
        double[] distancesFromSun = {0.39, 0.723, 1.0, 1.52, 5.20, 9.58, 19.18, 30.07};
        double[] orbitalPeriods = {88.0, 225.0, 365.25, 1.88, 11.86, 29.46, 84.02, 164.8};

        for (int i = 0; i < planetNames.length; i++) {
            CelestialBody body = new CelestialBody(planetNames[i], 1.0, planetSizes[i]*earthRadius, new Vector3D(0, 0, distancesFromSun[i]*oneAU), zeroVelocity, planetNames[i].toLowerCase() + ".jpg", orbitalPeriods[i] / earthOrbitalPeriod, false);

            Sphere sphere = new Sphere(body.getRadius());
            DisplayedCelestialBody displayedBody = new DisplayedCelestialBody(body, sphere);
            solarSystem.addBody(displayedBody);
        }

        return solarSystem;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

SolarSystemSimulation:

```
    public class SolarSystemSimulation extends Group {
    private SolarSystem solarSystem;
    private double anchorX, anchorY;
    private double anchorAngleX = 0;
    private double anchorAngleY = 0;

    public SolarSystemSimulation(SolarSystem solarSystem) {
        this.solarSystem = solarSystem;

        for (DisplayedCelestialBody displayedBody : solarSystem.getBodies()) {
            CelestialBody body = displayedBody.getCelestialBody();
            Sphere sphere = displayedBody.getDisplayObject();
            PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
            Image texture = loadImage(body.getTextureFilename());
            if (texture != null) {
                material.setDiffuseMap(texture);
            }
            sphere.setMaterial(material);
            getChildren().add(sphere);
        }

        // Wypisanie promieni sfer
        for (DisplayedCelestialBody displayedBody : solarSystem.getBodies()) {
            CelestialBody body = displayedBody.getCelestialBody();
            Sphere sphere = displayedBody.getDisplayObject();
            System.out.println("Promień " + body.getName() + ": " + sphere.getRadius());
        }
    }

    public void setRadius(DisplayedCelestialBody displayedBody, double radius) {
        Sphere sphere = displayedBody.getDisplayObject();
        sphere.setRadius(radius);
    }

    private Image loadImage(String filename) {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + filename);
        return new Image(inputStream);
    }

    public void updatePositions(double deltaTime) {
        List<DisplayedCelestialBody> bodies = solarSystem.getBodies();
        for (int i = 1; i < bodies.size(); i++) {
            DisplayedCelestialBody displayedBody = bodies.get(i);
            CelestialBody body = displayedBody.getCelestialBody();

            // Prędkość kątowa każdego ciała niebieskiego
            double angularSpeed = 2 * Math.PI / (body.getOrbitalSpeed() * 60);

            // Pomijamy aktualizacje pozycji dla "fixed" obiektów
            if (body.isFixed()) {
                continue;
            }

            // Obliczenie nowej pozycji ciała niebieskiego
            Vector3D currentPosition = body.getPosition();
            double angle = angularSpeed * deltaTime;
            double newX = currentPosition.getX() * Math.cos(angle) - currentPosition.getZ() * Math.sin(angle);
            double newZ = currentPosition.getX() * Math.sin(angle) + currentPosition.getZ() * Math.cos(angle);
            Vector3D newPosition = new Vector3D(newX, currentPosition.getY(), newZ);

            body.setPosition(newPosition);
            }
        }

    public void start() {
        setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            anchorX = event.getSceneX();
            anchorY = event.getSceneY();
            anchorAngleX = getRotate();
            anchorAngleY = getRotate();

        });

        setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            getTransforms().clear();
            Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(anchorAngleX + (event.getSceneY() - anchorY), Rotate.X_AXIS);
            Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(anchorAngleY - (event.getSceneX() - anchorX), Rotate.Y_AXIS);
            getTransforms().addAll(rotateX, rotateY);

        });

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                // Obliczamy różnicę czasu w sekundach
                double deltaTime = 1.0 / 60.0;

                updatePositions(deltaTime);

                List<DisplayedCelestialBody> sortedDisplayedBodies = new ArrayList<>(solarSystem.getBodies());
                sortedDisplayedBodies.sort((body1, body2) -> {
                    CelestialBody celestialBody1 = body1.getCelestialBody();
                    CelestialBody celestialBody2 = body2.getCelestialBody();
                    if (celestialBody1.getName().equals("Sun")) return 1;
                    else if (celestialBody2.getName().equals("Sun")) return -1;
                    else {
                        Sphere sphere1 = body1.getDisplayObject();
                        Sphere sphere2 = body2.getDisplayObject();
                        double distance1 = calculateDistanceToCamera(sphere1);
                        double distance2 = calculateDistanceToCamera(sphere2);
                        return Double.compare(distance2, distance1);
                    }
                });

                getChildren().clear();

                for (DisplayedCelestialBody displayedBody : sortedDisplayedBodies) {
                    CelestialBody body = displayedBody.getCelestialBody();
                    Sphere sphere = displayedBody.getDisplayObject();
                    sphere.setTranslateX(body.getPosition().getX());
                    sphere.setTranslateY(body.getPosition().getY());
                    sphere.setTranslateZ(body.getPosition().getZ());

                    body.updateRotation(deltaTime);

                    if (!body.getName().equals("Sun")) {
                        sphere.getTransforms().clear();
                        Rotate rotate = new Rotate(body.getRotationAngle(), Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                        sphere.getTransforms().add(rotate);
                    }

                    getChildren().add(sphere);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }


    private double calculateDistanceToCamera(Sphere sphere) {
        double cameraX = 0;  // Podstawowe wartości, jeśli kamera jest na pozycji (0,0,0)
        double cameraY = 0;
        double cameraZ = 0;
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sphere.getTranslateX() - cameraX, 2) +
                Math.pow(sphere.getTranslateY() - cameraY, 2) +
                Math.pow(sphere.getTranslateZ() - cameraZ, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `updatePositions` uses `body.isFixed()` which you haven't shown - and seems to contradict what is stated about `isImmovable`.

Comment: it is *very hard* to debug a program without having its source - usually better to include a [mre] in the question

Comment: I'd _expect_ the Sun to orbit the [barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter) of the bodies in a simulation.